What is the Puranic story behind the celebration of Bhatri Dvitiya or Bhai Tika or Bhai Dooj or Bhai Phonta or Bhagini Hasta Bhojanam?
Bhatri Dvitiya is a Hindu festival, where sisters put a tilak on the brother's forehead and wish them a long life. It is celebrated immediately after Diwali. In Bengal, this festival is known as Bhai Phonta. In North India, it is known as Bhai Dooj. In Nepal, it is celebrated as Bhai Tika. In Telangana, it is known as Bhagini Hasta Bhojanam.
What I know is that Yamuna the sister of Yama first started this celebration. Where can I find a reference to this (or any other story)?

It is called Bhagini Hastha Bhojanam/Karthika Vana Bhojanam in my native place. The story involves Yama and Yami afaik.

@Vatapatrashaayi You are from which place?

@ Amritendu Mukhopadhyay  Thelangana

Yama Dvitiya festival is described in Skanda Purana, Vaishnava Khanda, Kārttikamāsa-māhātmya, Chapter 11 (Skanda Purana 2.4.11) :

12-14. Then, O sage, he should go to the house of his own uterine sister and salute her with great devotion.

“O gentle lady, O my sister of good fortune, I have come to your abode in order to make obeisance to your lotus-like feet.”

16-18. After saying this to his sister, he should salute her, thinking
her to be Viṣṇu.
Then, on hearing the excellent words of her brother, O Nārada, the following words should be addressed by the sister to the brother:
“O my brother, today I have become blessed and auspicious, thanks to
you. O lamp of the family, today you should take your food in my house
for my longevity, O brother, on the second day in the bright half of
the month of Kārttika.

On this day formerly Yama was fed by Yamunā in her house and was duly honoured by her. Hell-dwellers were set free on this day by Yama.
Those who are fettered with the cords of Karma too, are roaming about
as they please.

20-22. The sins beginning with that of the slaughter of a Brāhmaṇa
shout thus: ‘We are very glad on receiving that sinful man who does
not take his food in the house of his sister, even on Yamadvitīyā day.
We have been without food (for a long time). We shall devour him
today.’
Hence, O my brother, take food in my house today, the second day in
the bright half of Kārttika well-known in all the three worlds. O
brother, learned men do not take food in their own house on this day.”

On being told thus, the devotee should worship his sister with garments, ornaments and embellishments with great delight, O highly
fortunate one.



Thanks to @ekAntika for referring to the Skanda Purana chapter (Skanda Purana 2.4.11). I see that another detailed version of the story is described in the same chapter. I just want to mention that too.
Vālakhilyas said:


The second day in the bright half of Kārttika is named after Yama. Then in the afternoon the worship of Yama should by all means be performed.



42-43. Formerly Yamunā used to come to Yama everyday with the request, “O brother, come to my house for food in the company of your attendants.” Everyday Yama used to reply that he would go “today or tomorrow or the day after.” There is no leisure to persons with minds engrossed in their duties.


44-46. Then once, he was invited with persistent solicitation, O great sages, on the Dvitīyā day in the month of Kārttika. He went there after setting free all the residents of hells. Accompanied by his attendants, the son of Sun was received with great hospitality by Yamunā. O bird, different kinds of dishes were prepared. He was anointed with oil by Yamunā and sweet-smelling, fascinating unguents were smeared upon his body. The son of Sun was bathed duly.


47-49. Then ornaments were presented to him along with different kinds of clothes, sandal paste, garlands etc. He was made to sit on a cot.


The gentle lady Yamunā cooked in gold vessels sweet rice dishes of various kinds with delighted mind and fed Yama.


After taking food, Yama honoured his sister with ornaments and different kinds of clothes. Then he said, “Q beautiful lady, choose your boon.” On hearing his words Yamunā spoke these words:

Yamunā said:

50-51. Come to my house for food every year. O Yama, all sinners are to be set free from hell today. Those who take food today from the hands of their sisters, should be happy. Grant them happiness. I choose only this.

Yama said:

52-53. O Yamunā, he who takes his bath in Yamunā and offers libations to Pitṛs and Devas, he who takes food in the house of his sister and worships her, shall never see the entrance to my abode.

Also,

57-59. After worshipping Yameśvara he should go to the house of his sister. With the following Mantra he should be respectfully fed at the outset by her:


भ्रातस्तवानुजाताहं भुङ्क्ष भक्तमिदं शुभम्।
प्रीतये यमराजस्य यमुनाया विशेषतः॥ ५८


bhrātastavānujātāhaṃ bhuṅkṣa bhaktamidaṃ śubham।
prītaye yamarājasya yamunāyā viśeṣataḥ॥ 58


“O brother, I am your younger sister. Eat this splendid food for the delight of Yamarāja and Yamunā in particular.”


He should then propitiate his sister with garments, ornaments etc. Thereby, he will not see the world of Yama even in dreams.


60-65. If one has no younger sister,[2] one shall go to the elder sister’s house. If she too does not exist, he should go to the abode of the married daughter of his paternal uncle.


In her absence, to the house of mother’s sister or to that of the maternal uncle’s daughter. The order of precedence shall be fixed on the basis of the relationships as the children of co-wives or of the same Gotra.


In the absence of all these, some lady should be considered as a sister. If she too is not available, one should make a cow or a river as his sister, in the absence thereof, the devotee should make a forest his sister’s house. O gentle lady, one must not take one’s food in one’s own house on this day.


70. The span of life of the brother too shall not decrease at all.

